# Set Assembly Version in AssemblyInfo.cs using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: .net, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

There is a way to change Assembly Version in Jenkins Pipeline,
like it can be with the `Change Assembly Version` plugin?

Finally I got the `svn revision` number but i can't use it for the purpose.

Comment: I guess this is wrongly tagged [assembly] (read the tag description), but I'm not sure which assembly you talk about... .net maybe?

Comment: OK, fixed it.Thank you

Comment: There is an answer??

Comment: see accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274254/setting-the-version-number-for-net-core-projects-csproj-not-json-projects/43280282#43280282