# Azure DevOps increase VersionPrefix with each commit

Tags: azure-devops, commit, versioning

Anyone know how increase the `VersionPrefix` on the .csproj file with each commit?

That property is used to name the package when you push the package on a feed (Nuget push operation)...

> 2018-11-14T16:15:59.3937162Z ##[error]Error: An unexpected error
>   occurred while trying to push the package with VstsNuGetPush.exe. Exit
>   code(2) and error(The feed already contains 'Lib 1.0.15-alpha'.)

Comment: The error occurs in the azure devops build?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274254/setting-the-version-number-for-net-core-projects-csproj-not-json-projects) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4859#issuecomment-289040935)

Comment: Shayki Abramczyk, yes, it occurs on the build process (one of the steps is make a push to a Visual Devops feed)

Comment: Thanks, Jayendran, I'll try it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. There is a extension on Visual Studio Marketplace, **Version number counter** that increase a variable defined in *Variables Section* of the pipeline. Just, define the variable, add a new step (task) on the pipeline of **Version number counter** and set the variable to increase.

Finally, you can use $(VariableName) on your code to reference to the Azure DevOps variable. In my case, $(BuildVersionNumber) was enough.

I hope this help to other people.

Thanks to Jayendran and Shayki Abramczyk for your answers :)