# How To Set Version Number For A C# Win Forms App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and have just created a new Win Form Application.
Currently the version number of my newly  created app is 1.0.0

How can I change this in the designer

I have looked under properties of the project but cannot see anything related to these properties.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274254/setting-the-version-number-for-net-core-projects-csproj-not-json-projects

Comment: I appreciate the link but I wanted to do it via the designer rather then in the file

Comment: Clearly you are not used to .NETCore projects, editing the project file is considered entirely normal and often a hard necessity.  Right-click the project in the Solution Explorer window and select "Edit Project File".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under **Project -> Properties** go to **Package -> General** and there you can enter **Assembly Version** and **File Version**.

[image]

Comment: Thank You, I think they have changed this since I last used VS 2019 as it looks different in some areas. Got there in the end, thanks for the quick reply.