# dotnet restore issue NETSDK1018 Invalid NuGet version string: '0.0.0+main.'

Tags: .net

When using docker to build a aspnet application, I ran into the issue of getting this error:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.304/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets(209,5): error NETSDK1018: Invalid NuGet version string: '0.0.0+main.'.  [/src/myproject.csproj]
```

Using image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0.304-alpine3.18`

Turns out that the fix for this was to set the following in the `.csproj` file:

```
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I created this project in `Rider`, maybe that caused it to not have this `GenerateAssemblyInfo` value?

Also leaving this for future me if I ever need to search that error again and nothing really comes up.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: add `--property AssemblyVersion={foo}`

```
RUN dotnet build -c Release --property AssemblyVersion=1.2.3.4
```

Longer version:

I had this same issue but with a couple unit tests that depended on the `InternalsVisibleTo` assembly attribute (which apparently requires `GenerateAssemblyInfo` to be `true` for it to work, so I couldn't use the OP's solution).

After some research I found another answer on SO (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45426330), which led me to add the argument `--property AssemblyVersion={foo}`.