# How to set the version number in a Console App

Tags: c#

I'm learning c# and have built my first little CLI, now I want to version it but can't figure out the correct way.

I've been reading through this page -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/set-attributes

but when I create the following `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```cs
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

I get the following error:

`Duplicate 'AssemblyInformationalVersion' attribute Roslyn(CS0579)`

What am I missing and what is the correct way to add version information to a c# console app?

Thanks

Comment: You should set the version in the project properties. Have a thorough look through those properties to see what is there and what may be useful now or in the future.

Comment: It depends on whether you're using .NET Framework or .NET. Since you just started out I am assuming you're using a recent .NET version i. e. .NET 6 or .NET 7. In that case have a look as this question which should be a duplicate: [Setting the version number for .NET Core projects - CSPROJ - not JSON projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274254/setting-the-version-number-for-net-core-projects-csproj-not-json-projects)

Comment: The default for SDK-style projects is to use project properties to set this, but if for some reason you want to put that information in an "AssemblyInfo.cs" file, you can add the following to your ".csproj" file: `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>`

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, all sorted now, I'll add an answer for others to find. I was searching for c#, not .Net, my bad - still finding my way around the whole ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those who commented. The comment from @mushroomator pointed me in the right direction for what I was specifically looking for.

In my `.csproj` file I added the following line:

```
<Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
```

And then to print it out to the console when required I added the following lines to my `Program.cs`

```cs
using System.Reflection;

// The following outputs the version number

Assembly? assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
AssemblyName? assemblyName = assembly?.GetName();
Version? version = assemblyName?.Version;

if (version is not null)
    Console.WriteLine(version.ToString());
```