# Custom ProductVersion string in .NET 6

Tags: .net, visual-studio, version, .net-6.0, csproj

I am developing a `.NET 6` web application and I have a requirement to set the `ProductVersion` (or, if that is impossible, at least `FileVersion`) of the assembly to a custom string, like shown here:

[image]

However, I can't figure out how to do it. All the versioning properties I see in the .csproj file seem to expect a specific numeric format like `x.y.z` or something similar.

Is there a way to do this in the `.csproj` file, without having to patch the final compiled assembly?

Comment: Have you seen this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274254/setting-the-version-number-for-net-core-projects-csproj-not-json-projects)?

Comment: @AxelKemper: the answer in that post suggests using VersionPrefix+VersionSuffix. However, unfortunately VersionPrefix still needs to be in the form x.y.z, so with 3 pieces. In my case I need it to be only 2. I tried setting only 2 but in that case the compiler seems to add a `.0` automatically at the end... I tried various combinations but I couldn't replicate the version string shown in the screenshot I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `InformationalVersion` is mapped to `ProductVersion`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <InformationalVersion>1.24asdds</InformationalVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Result:

[image]

If you are using .NET 8 SDK to build - do not forget to [set `IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion` to `false`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/8.0/source-link#recommended-action):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <InformationalVersion>1.24asdds</InformationalVersion>
    <IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>
         false
    </IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```