# dll file vs exe File and Product version differ in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core app that I set the version in the csproj file.

[image]

When I do dotnet publish I can see that the version in the dll file is different than the one in exe file

[image]

Why is this happening? Since they are the same file they shouldn't have exactly the same versions?

Comment: you might be help this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752162/whats-the-difference-between-a-dlls-fileversion-and-productversion)

Comment: No didn't help. The link is for file and product version. The issue I have is the version between the dll and exe file under the same name that are produced and they have different versions

Comment: I'm afraid it is resulted from the configuration or the packaging process. I just find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24766769) which can edit the file version.

Comment: Did you use `dotnet clean` before building and publishing? If all that changed is `Version`, the compiler may have skipped building the unchanged dll. What happens when you publish *after* deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders?

Comment: When you set `ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles` property to `true` what are your conflicting files? Are any of them `dll` or `exe`?