# Add a bindingRedirect to the web.config declaratively in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-config, declarative

It is possible to add keys to the web.config by creating a file: 12/CONFIG/webconfig.name.xml
(See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413929.aspx)
With contents:

```
<actions>
<add path="configuration/SharePoint/SafeControls">
    <SafeControl
        Assembly="CustomWebPart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123456789abcdefgABC"
        Namespace="CustomWebPart"
        TypeName="*"
        Safe="True" />
</add>
<add path="configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding">
  <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="CustomWebPart" publicKeyToken="123456789abcdefgABC" culture="neutral" />
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</actions>
```

This works great for adding safe controls, but it doens't seem to work for assembly redirects. Does anyone have an idea why this doens't work? Is it maybe the case only tags inside "configuration/SharePoint/" can be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add binding redirects on deployment with configuration files in SharePoint 2007 (though you can in 2010) so you would have to write code to do this using [SPWebConfigModification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861909(v=office.12).aspx).

Beware though its not easy - just search on SPWebConfigModification and check out the first page of results.

As an alternative I've got to ask why you might want to do this - if this is just versioning minor changes (i.e. v1.1 > v1.2) then perhaps this is not the best way to do this - check out [file assembly versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035284/sharepoint-features-how-can-i-use-wildcard-assembly-versioning) instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It seems it is nowhere documented that binding redirects can't be used tih configuration files in SharePoint 2007. I ended up using a manual deployment step to change the web.config due to time constraints. 
Next time I'll look into the SPWebConfigModification. Though I guess the SPWebConfigModification will need to be used from a feature receiver and I can't guarantee that the code will then run as a user with sufficient priviliges to edit the web.config.