# Webpart "Not registered as safe" after changing AssemblyVersion

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I (successfully) deployed some sharepoint2010 - Webparts using msbuild. Everything works fine until I decided to change the assemblyVersion. Whenever I do that the message

> Web Part Error: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported.
>   The type RTContacts, RTContacts,
>    Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2721ba85ef1e4b88 could not be found or it is not registered as safe.

A solution would be to stay on 1.0.0.0, but there should be a better way...

Perhaps interesting to mention is that we use a centralized AssemblyFile which is included as a link.

The manifest contains the correct assemblyversion:

```
<Assemblies>
<Assembly Location="RTContacts.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache">
  <SafeControls>
    <SafeControl Assembly="RTContacts, Version=1.0.4325.18399, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2721ba85ef1e4b88" Namespace="RTContacts" TypeName="*" />
  </SafeControls>
</Assembly>
```

When I add the WebPart again to that Site, it is displayed correctly, but already existing webParts seem to link to the old version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having these problems because you're using the versioning attributes incorrectly.

If you examine, for example, Microsoft.SharePoint.dll in Reflector you will see v14.0.0.0 (for SharePoint 2010).

This **AssemblyVersion** will stay exactly the same for Beta, RCx, RTM all service packs and CU's etc - the only thing that changes is the **AssemblyFileVersion** (this is the thing you see in Windows Explorer under properties)

See this for more details

[SharePoint features: How can I use wildcard assembly versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035284/sharepoint-features-how-can-i-use-wildcard-assembly-versioning)

But don't take my word for it - Microsoft [KB556041 - How to use Assembly Version and Assembly File Version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556041)

If you follow this then no Assembly binding redirections are necessary and when you update your web part the existing instances will not be broken.

Comment: We decided to do a "dirty" solution. Leave the AssemblyVersion on 1.0.0.0 and using AssemblyTitle to save "our" version number. In combination with a webpart that shows the AssemblyTitle of all webparts this is a dirty but working solution for us.

Comment: Its only a tiny step from 'dirty' to correct - leave AssemblyVersion as 1 and put your version info in AssemblyFileVersion. You can even output the AssemblyFileVersion info on the web part (I put it in a toolpart for easy troubleshooting). Job done.

Comment: its been a while. Just wanted to tell you we did the clean solution after a while :)

Answer (score 2):

<sub>**Original question:** How to fix the "Not registered as safe" error after the assembly version has been changed?</sub>

Web Parts are registered as safe in the `web.config` files.

Appropriate entry looks like this:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="MyWebPartLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
  Namespace="MyWebPartLibrary"
  TypeName="*"
  Safe="True"
  AllowRemoteDesigner="True"/>
```

Modify the `Assembly` attribute and replace the old version number with a new one.

<sub>**Current question:** How can I change assembly version without having to re-add all the Web Parts to the page?</sub>

I think you'll need to use **assembly redirection** to keep existing Web Part instances working:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="RTContacts" publicKeyToken="2721ba85ef1e4b88" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.4325.18399" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Read the article [Web Part Versioning with assembly redirection](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Web-Part-Versioning-with-assembly-redirection.aspx) for a detailed analysis of this problem.

Comment: GAC, manifest and web.config are all the same and correct, but restart did not help

Comment: Oh. I just found out that the message said that V 1.0.0.0 cannot be found. Sorry I did not mention it early but that information was hidden behind another layer.

Comment: I just updated the description: The Webparts that are already on my Pages throw the error. If I add the same Webpart again on that Page it works correctly. Re-adding all webparts each time we deploy a new version would be a bit of a hazzle as there are about 10.000 Pages already in the project. Also I am absolutely sure that we did not have any hardcoded version in our webparts. I wrote that completely by myself and there is not much magic in there

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Not really a "nice" solution but the best that can be done in sharepoint, I think.

Comment: Chaps - you're making really hard work of this! See my answer for the recommended method that doesn't have these problems.

Comment: @Ryan Downvoting my answer seems to be a little harsh, but +1 for the KB556041 link nonetheless.

Comment: Sorry Marek - but I just don't agree that this is the right way to tackle this scenario and voting is how you make your opinions known on SO. It was nothing personal and I do heavily upvote as well!