# Assembly File Version not changing?

Tags: c#, version-control, assemblies

I have in my  assemblyinfo.cs class the code:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Calling `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()` works fine and gives the updated version, however, when i look at the generated dll in windows explorer, right click properties, click the 'details' tab, the fileversion says "1.0.0.0" even though the output above says 1.0.3489.17621 ?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual studio 2008, doh!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602/what-are-differences-between-assemblyversion-assemblyfileversion-and-assemblyin

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You cannot use 1.0.* to auto-increment the AssemblyFileVersion, only the AssemblyVersion. (Checked in all Visual Studio versions from 2005 to 2012).

Comment out the following line

> [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]

and the File Version will take the same number as the Assembly Version.

Comment: Works, im using vs2008 so it seems to have carried over.

Comment: Horrible situation, caught me out myself last year, fingers crossed for 2010!

Comment: Unfortunately it appears they haven't changed it.
I get this:
<code>
warning CS1607: Assembly generation -- The version '1.0.*' specified for the 'file version' is not in the normal 'major.minor.build.revision' format
</code>

Comment: Seems the same way with VS 2012.

Answer (score 23):

Patrick already gave the correct answer, but here is just a little advice. If you look into AssemblyInfo.cs you'll find the following block at the end:

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
//[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Now go on and flip the comment from the last three lines as follows:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

And everything works as expected... :-)

Comment: Excellente, gave the answer tag to Patrick but would've given it twice if i could :D

Comment: Interesting that trying to blank out the AssemblyFileVersion in the GUI doesn't let you until you comment it out like this says. Thanks!