# Check VS version of a C# Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a completed C# Visual Studio project but I am not able to open it due to version issue of the Visual Studios.

I have tried using VS2005 and VS2010, but both are unable to open the project.

I met errors while converting the project in VS2010 as well.

Is there any file which I could locate the version of VS used?

__

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the advices.

I have look through my csproj file as advised:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`

From what I see, the VS ver. used is most likely to be 2003 ver.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What controls the ProductVersion setting in .csproj files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299492/what-controls-the-productversion-setting-in-csproj-files)

Answer (score 31):

Look for the value in the `<ProductVersion>` tag in your project's csproj file.

Here's a [table with each product name and its corresponding version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History):

```
+---------------------------+---------------+-----------+----------------+
|       Product name        |   Codename    | Version # | .NET Framework | 
+---------------------------+---------------+-----------+----------------+
| Visual Studio 4.0         | N/A           | 4.0.*     | N/A            |
| Visual Studio 97          | Boston        | 5.0.*     | N/A            |
| Visual Studio 6.0         | Aspen         | 6.0.*     | N/A            |
| Visual Studio .NET (2002) | Rainier       | 7.0.*     | 1              |
| Visual Studio .NET 2003   | Everett       | 7.1.*     | 1.1            |
| Visual Studio 2005        | Whidbey       | 8.0.*     | 2.0, 3.0       |
| Visual Studio 2008        | Orcas         | 9.0.*     | 2.0, 3.0, 3.5  |
| Visual Studio 2010        | Dev10/Rosario | 10.0.*    | 2.0 – 4.0      |
| Visual Studio 2012        | Dev11         | 11.0.*    | 2.0 – 4.5.2    |
| Visual Studio 2013        | Dev12         | 12.0.*    | 2.0 – 4.5.2    |
| Visual Studio 2015        | Dev14         | 14.0.*    | 2.0 – 4.6      |
+---------------------------+---------------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: I don't believe this answer is complete.  ProductVersion in an upgraded csproj that I have modified using VS2015 Pro Update3 is 9.0.30729. ProductVersion in a brand new SL5 application, created using VS2015 Pro Update3 is 8.0.50727.  According to the table above, I would expect 14.0.something in both cases, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 7):

Open up the .sln file in a text editor such as notepad.  The version should be in the first few lines following a "#" symbol.

Answer (score 1):

The beginning of a project file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">   <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
```

Either the `ToolsVersion` attribute or `ProductVersion` tag should lead you to the version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I have the same *.csproj file like your answer, so could you tell me what's your Visual Studio version?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Ben's answer, you can take a look at project types, in the same csproj file, they will look like this:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

It's possible that the project you are trying to open is using some project type that you don't have installed (like web deployment project or a version of MVC higher than what you have etc.) You can google each of teh GUID's in the ProjectTypeGuids to see what's missing.

Answer (score -1):

Open the csproj file with notepad.  There should be a line in there.

You are correct.  It's Visual Studio 2003.

Comment: 2003 is the just the schema version, nothing to do with the VS version. dotNet 4.0 wasn't possible in VS2003.