# Create a dll from vb project

Tags: vb.net, dll

I have one beautiful *myname*.dll that I used in my programs. But today I have to change something in it source. It is writen in VB, an source have such structure:
files

```
SysCommandVB.ico
SysCommandVB.resx
SysCommandVB.vb
SysCommandVB.vbproj
SysCommandVBForm.Designer.vb
SysCommandVBForm.resx
SysCommandVBForm.vb
```

and folder My Project, witch contains

```
Application.Designer.vb
Application.myapp
AssemblyInfo.vb
Resources.Designer.vb
Resources.resx
Settings.Designer.vb 
Settings.settings
```

I have made some changes in file

```
SysCommandVB.vb
```

Ok, now, how can I get (modified) *myname*.dll from this files?

Comment: Retagged; Thats VB.Net not VB6

Comment: Are you asking how to compile it or .... ?

Comment: [How to: Compile and Run a Project in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233809.aspx)

Comment: I honestly don't understand the downvotes. It's a very basic question, but it's a clear, on-topic question.

Comment: Just for notice: I never worked before with "compiled" languages (I have worked with SQL, SAS, R, VBA, Mathematica, Autoit, even Pascal - but not with this). So, I just lose courage, what to do with all this ... large count of files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a new DLL by **compiling** your VB.NET project. "Compiling" is the process of translating source code files (such as your .vb files) into executable files (such as your .dll file)¹.

You can compile your project by opening your .vbproj file with [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) and selecting "Build Solution" from the menu. The new DLL can be found in the `bin` subfolder.

---

¹ Technically speaking, "compiling" just means translation from one programming language into another.

Comment: Thanks. I have installed Visual Studi 2005 at my work, and when I try to open .vbproj file I get an error: Unable to read the project file '...vbproj': The imported project C:\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets was not found. Confirm that the parth in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exist on disk

Comment: Have I Installed newer version of Visual Studio, or doing something other?

Comment: @burduk: Yes, it looks like your project was created with another version of Visual Studio. Please [check the version number in your vbproj file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8829542/87698).

Comment: I have got this: `<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">` - so it seems like 2003 Visual studio... Dut I have also this line: `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />` I think trouble is somewhere here...

Comment: `ToolsVersion="3.5"` implies Framework 3.5, which was introduced in Visual Studio 2008.