# GetFileVersionInfo returning incorrect fileVersion for SQLOLEDB.dll

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe6, delphi-5, sqloledb

## Short Version

File version of `SqlOledB.dll`:

- **Actual:** `10.0.18362.1`
- **[GetFileVersionInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfow)**: `6.2.18362.1`

## Long Version

I am trying to get the **file version** of the Windows dll `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\sqloledb.dll"`

In Windows Explorer, I can see:

- File version: 10.0.18362.1
- Product version: 10.0.18362.1

[image]

When I use Powershell:

```
> [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\sqloledb.dll") | Format-List -property *
```

I can see the file version:

```
FileVersionRaw     : 10.0.18362.1
ProductVersionRaw  : 10.0.18362.1
Comments           :
CompanyName        : Microsoft Corporation
FileBuildPart      : 18362
FileDescription    : OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
FileMajorPart      : 10
FileMinorPart      : 0
FileName           : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\sqloledb.dll
FilePrivatePart    : 1
FileVersion        : 10.0.18362.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
InternalName       : sqloledb.dll
IsDebug            : False
IsPatched          : False
IsPrivateBuild     : False
IsPreRelease       : False
IsSpecialBuild     : False
Language           : English (United States)
LegalCopyright     : © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
LegalTrademarks    :
OriginalFilename   : sqloledb.dll
PrivateBuild       :
ProductBuildPart   : 18362
ProductMajorPart   : 10
ProductMinorPart   : 0
ProductName        : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
ProductPrivatePart : 1
ProductVersion     : 10.0.18362.1
SpecialBuild       :
```

When I look at the VersionInfo resource in the DLL, I see the file and product versions match:

```
1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 10,0,18362,1
PRODUCTVERSION 10,0,18362,1
FILEOS 0x40004
FILETYPE 0x2
{
BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
{
    BLOCK "040904B0"
    {
        VALUE "CompanyName", "Microsoft Corporation"
        VALUE "FileDescription", "OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"
        VALUE "FileVersion", "10.0.18362.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)"
        VALUE "InternalName", "sqloledb.dll"
        VALUE "LegalCopyright", "© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved."
        VALUE "OriginalFilename", "sqloledb.dll"
        VALUE "ProductName", "Microsoft® Windows® Operating System"
        VALUE "ProductVersion", "10.0.18362.1"
    }
}

BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
{
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0409 0x04B0
}
}
```

When I use PEView to view the raw version resource, I see `000A0000 47BA0001` for both the file and product versions. I also see the file info string section that says:

- "FileVersion": "10.0.18362.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)"
- "ProductVersion": "10.0.183612.1"

And when I use **Process Monitor**, I can see my application querying the correct DLL:

[image]

But, when I query it from code, I get the wrong value!

When my 32-bit application calls:

- [`GetFileVersionInfoSizeW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfosizew)
- [`GetFileVersionInfoW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfow)
- [`VerQueryValueW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-verqueryvaluew) (querying for `"\"`)

and look at the contents of the returned `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` buffer, I see:

- dwSignature: 4277077181
- dwStrucVersion: 65536
- dwFileVersionMS: 393218
- dwFileVersionLS: 1203372033
- dwProductVersionMS: 655360
- dwProductVersionLS: 1203372033
- dwFileFlagsMask: 63
- dwFileFlags: 0
- dwFileOS: 262148
- dwFileType: 2
- dwFileSubtype: 0
- dwFileDateMS: 0
- dwFileDateLS: 0

If you look at the fileVersion and productVersion values, and convert them to hex:

| Field | Decimal | Hex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dwFileVersionMS | 393218 | 0x00060002 |
| dwFileVersionLS | 1203372033 | 0x47BA0001 |
| dwProductVersionMS | 655360 | 0x000A0000 |
| dwProductVersionLS | 1203372033 | 0x47BA0001 |

Which gives you the versions in hex of:

- **File Version:** `0x0006`, `0x0002`, `0x47BA`, `0x0001`
- **Product Version:** `0x000A`, `0x0000`, `0x47BA`, `0x0001`

We get the versions as decimal strings:

- **File Version:** 6.2.18362.1
- **Product Version:** 10.0.13621.1

The *product version* is correct, but the *file version* is completely wrong.

Which begs the questions:

- Where is the [`GetFileVersion()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfoa) API function ***possibly*** getting version `6.2.x.x` from; when everything about the DLL binary says `10.0.x.x`?
- Is there an appcompat shim kicking in; lying to me about the version number so that it's Windows **6.2** rather than Windows **10.0**?
- Do I need to update my `SupportedOS` entries in my assembly manifest?

Short Version: How is Windows returning a version value that does not exist anywhere in the binary?

### [CRME for the lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72189969/12597)

```pascal
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

function GetFileVersion(Filename: WideString): string;
var
    dwHandle: Cardinal;
    dwInfoLength: Cardinal;
    pInfoData: Pointer;
    lengthOfReturned: Cardinal;
    value: Pointer;
    fileInfo: PVSFixedFileInfo;
    iMajor, iMinor, iBuild, iRelease: Integer;
begin
    Result := '?.?.?.?';

    // Get the number of bytes he have to allocate for the file information structure
    dwHandle := 0;
    dwInfoLength := GetFileVersionInfoSizeW(PWideChar(Filename), {var}dwHandle);
    if dwInfoLength = 0 then
        Exit;

    // Allocate the memory needed to hold the file info
    GetMem(pInfoData, dwInfoLength);
    try
        //Put the information into the buffer we just allocated
        if not GetFileVersionInfoW(PWideChar(Filename), 0, dwInfoLength, pInfoData) then
            Exit;

        // Extract the desired data from pInfoData into the FileInformation structure
        value := nil;
        lengthOfReturned := 0;
        if not VerQueryValueW(pInfoData, '\', {var}value, {var}lengthOfReturned) then
            Exit;

        fileInfo := PVSFixedFileInfo(value);

        iMajor := fileInfo.dwFileVersionMS shr 16;
        iMinor := fileInfo.dwFileVersionMS and $FFFF;
        iRelease := fileInfo.dwFileVersionLS shr 16;
        iBuild := fileInfo.dwFileVersionLS and $FFFF;
    finally
        FreeMem(pInfoData);
    end;

    Result := Format('%d.%d.%d.%d', [iMajor, iMinor, iRelease, iBuild]);
end;

procedure Main;
var
    filename: string;
    version: string;
begin
    filename := 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\sqloledb.dll';
    version := GetFileVersion(filename);

    WriteLn('Filename:     '+filename);
    WriteLn('File version: '+version);
end;


begin
    Main;

    WriteLn('Press enter to close...');
    ReadLn;
end.
```

### Bonus Chatter

I also tried using the *ANSI* versions (with ANSI strings), in case the legacy ANSI version had some app-compat feature that lies about version numbers.

Tried in Delphi 5 and Delphi XE6 - both 32-bit apps.

### Bonus Reading

- [GetFileVersionInfo() returns wrong file's version information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263954/)

Comment: *"Is there an appcompat shim kicking in?"* - Probably. *"Do i need to update my `SupportedOS` entires in my assembly manifest?"* - Incredibly likely. The hint is in your first screenshot where it reads: *"Product Name: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System"*. You're asking an operating system component about its version information, and that is subject to general operating system version compatibility shenanigans.

Comment: @IInspectable Well that did it. Adding the Windows 10 id `<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>` makes it return the correct value. In my case, i need to ensure that sqloledb.dll supports TLS 1.2, which was only added after "build" 17763. So i guess rather than checking just for version `10.0.17763.0`, i can also check that the build in `6.2.17763.0` is at least 17763.  Phrase your comment as an answer and you'll get the rep.

Comment: you can direct access `VS_VERSIONINFO_HEADER` (as  `RT_VERSION, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1)` resource ) and get from it real `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO`. this will be not depend from any manifest

Comment: Why does one of your headers link to https://stackoverflow.com/q/72189969/12597, which seems unrelated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is an app-compat shim kicking in - lying to me about the version of the `.dll` i use.

Adding the **Windows 10** entry

```
<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
```

to my `Assembly.manifest` fixes it.