# Getting error "add assembly="Oracle.DataAccess,Version=someversion, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=somenumbers"/"

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio, .net-assembly

for example, can I have a label in my asp.net webpage, and it's text can be assigned to the version of the oracle dll when running the project? Is there a method so that I can know the version of the oracle dll?

Please exclude viewing the property window of the oracle.DataAccess, I want to make sure if it's version 2.112.1.0 or 4.112.1.0. I installed the 4.112.1.0, but in my computer assembly folder, the Oracle.DataAccess still only has version 2.112.1.0.

I am keeping getting error of this line:

```
<add assembly="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=somenumbers"/>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can refer the below question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537731/version-number-of-a-dll-in-net

Comment: @user2846413 :Thank you =D

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem from searching here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1297159.aspx
msavva
1) create a new Application Pool

2) go to the Advanced Settings of this application pool

3) set the Enable 32-Bit Application to True

4) point your web application to use this new Pool

==============================
Application Pool is go to Control Panel on your PC, Administrative tools --> IIS Manager
for assignng application tool, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545625(v=cs.70).aspx
in my case, I followed the windows server 2008 procedures.

Thanks.