# Override Build Number and Revision in TFS 2010 build

Tags: tfsbuild

I modified my project's AssemblyInfo.cs as following:

```
[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
//[assembly:AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

This updated the dll file version. However, the Build Number and Revision number appear to be some random integers. Is it possible to specify the start point for Build/Revision number or override them while using TFS 2010 build ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the meaning of * I would take a look at [What are differences between AssemblyVersion, AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyInformationalVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602/what-are-differences-between-assemblyversion-assemblyfileversion-and-assemblyinf)

To increment automaticaly the build numbers I would implement the AssemblyInfoTask http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AssemblyInfoTaskvers

I would follow the steps in http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx to increment automaticaly the version in TFS 2010.