# What causes AssemblyInformationVersion to appear in some but not all AssemblyInfo.cs files?

Tags: c#

i have just started at a new company where i am basically looking after solution builds using TFS 2010. i have added a few new custom activities to increase version numbers in the AssemblyInfo files of the projects and this is working fine. The problem im finding is that all AssemblyInfo.cs files have the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion numbers, but only some have an AssemblyInformationVersion number aswell. Can anyone please tell me what causes the AssemblyInformationVersion to appear in some AssemblyInfo.cs files and not others?

Thanks

Comment: what kind of projects are you finding this to occur in? If you look at the TFS history of those AssemblyInfo.cs files, were those attributes ever removed at some point?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602/what-are-differences-between-assemblyversion-assemblyfileversion-and-assemblyinf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[AssemblyInformationalVersion]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute.aspx) is an optional attribute that maps to the [ProductVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.productversion.aspx) property of the application. If it is not present, the value specified in the [[AssemblyVersion]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx) attribute is used instead.

As far as I can tell, Visual Studio never adds `[AssemblyInformationalVersion]` attributes to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` files it generates. The developers might have added those if they wanted the product version to be different from the assembly version in some of your projects.