# How do I resolve this Kinect error: Add an AssemblyVersion attribute to 'Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.dll'

Tags: c#, kinect

I am developing an app with Microsoft's Kinect SDK (version 1.5), but code generates a warning message:

> CA1016 : Microsoft.Design : Add an AssemblyVersion attribute to 'Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.dll'.

How do I fix it?

Comment: This is happening when you try to include the DLL? What code exactly is generating this?

Comment: Is it just a warning? Or is it an actual error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an important error. An [Assembly version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374234(v=vs.85).aspx) is just what version of your software it is. You can easily fix this.

> Simply go to your project -> properties -> application -> Assembly Information and you will see a box like this

[image: link]

[image: link2]

Just change the Assembly Version, save and you should be fine. Hope this helps!

*Note: You may want to see [What are differences between AssemblyVersion, AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyInformationalVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602/what-are-differences-between-assemblyversion-assemblyfileversion-and-assemblyin) for more details*