# nuget pack [someProject.csproj] won't let me change title or description

Tags: nuget

I know I can change the author and the description if I specify a nuspec in my package (i.e. `nuget pack someSpec.nuspec`), but I want my project to the be the "one source of truth". Unfortunately, I can't seem to change the title/description/author via a command line switch. I figured this would work:

```
nuget pack Persistence.csproj -properties Title=Company.Project.Persistence -IncludeReferencedProjects -o bin\nuget_build
```

but this doesn't work. Can I do this via command line switch?

Comment: Similar question [NuSpec version attribute vs assembly version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11965924)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After much surfing, it would appear that the only way to change them is by modifying the attributes in `AssemblyInfo.cs` in your project. [click here to see the nuget codeplex discussion](https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/256959)

- `Title` maps to `[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Nuget.Package.Title")]`
- `Version` maps to `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]`
- `Author` maps to `[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Microsoft")]`
- `Description` maps to `[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]`

This seems to have gotten me the desired effect.

Also, the above link says that `Id` points to `AssemblyTitle`, but as of Nuget 2.8, it would appear that `Title` points to `AssemblyTitle` and the `Id` points to the name of the assembly in the project properties.