# Azure dll version debug difficulty

Tags: azure

In visual studio properties window a dll has a version given. And in OS file system another version number is given. Is there a way to see the same version shown in visual studio in file system or the other way around. Because with caching preview installation life has become very very difficult!!!  For visuals [click here](http://azuretable.blogspot.nl/2012/08/azure-version-conflict-sucks.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is because the file system displays the **[Assembly File Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.aspx)** and Visual Studio shows you the **[Assembly Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx)**. See this question for more info about the differences: [What are differences between AssemblyVersion, AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyInformationalVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602/what-are-differences-between-assemblyversion-assemblyfileversion-and-assemblyin)

If you open the assembly with DotPeek for example, you'll see that both attributes are defined:

```
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Windows Azure SDK")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.InternalAccessor, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9")]
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
[assembly: SecurityTransparent]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints)]
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Extension]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("StorageClientConvenienceTests, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudDrive, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Microsoft Corporation")]
---> HERE: [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("6.0.6002.18488")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Internal, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("StorageClientProtocolTests, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("StorageClientProtocolBillingTests, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.Internal, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9")]
---> HERE: [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.7.0.0")]
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to what is mentioned above, if the assembly is a standard assembly or from someone who is using AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion in the standard way, if the major and minor version for the two match, you are looking at the same assembly. For example, if you have 1.2.34.45 as the AssemblyFileVersion visible in explorer and 1.2 as the AssemblyVersion in the properties windows, its probably the same file.