# why is windows file version different from actual assembly version for a C++/CLR assembly

Tags: clr, assemblyversions, ilspy

I have a 3rd party C++/CLR assembly. When I right click the dll, the version tab shows 5.32.1 but when the meta information in ILSpy shows 5.0.0. Why is this difference? Which one is the one that is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file version as it's shown in property tab of Windows Explorer corresponds to the .NET assembly `AssemblyInformationalVersion` attribute. `AssemblyVersion` is a separate independent thing.

And of course, neither of the two is more correct than the other one, the developer can set them independently.

For the `AssemblyVersion` the current practice seems to be roughly "the assemblies with the same major.minor version should be compatible", but nothing really enforces this rule.

---

Necessary correction: Actually, the policy enforced by the current CLR assembly binding is that the *whole* assembly version should match in order to be loadable, so the compatible assemblies should have the *same* assembly version. More on the topic: [What are differences between AssemblyVersion, AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyInformationalVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64602/276994)

Comment: When I use codebase tag for a version, I know it uses the AssemblyVersion to match and load the file otherwise fails.

Comment: I;ve run into problems when I relied on AssemblyInformationalversion in my config to load the file....and it fails. Alas its Microsoft..

Comment: yes, when you reference a .NET assembly, you _may_ say that you want a specific version

Comment: app.config, publisher policy, machine.config - all interpret version attribute as AssemblyVersion

Comment: @user: oh yes, in the .NET world `AssemblyInformationalVersion` seems to be neglected, and exists perhaps only for the property tab display. Seems to be quite strange.

Comment: @user: ([this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z.aspx) might be somewhat helpful)