# "AssemblyInfo" MSBuild task failing in Jenkins build

Tags: c#, msbuild, jenkins

I'm getting this build error on Jenkins.  I'd appreciate any help hunting down a solution for it, or even someone to point me in the right direction.

This is the error I'm getting:

> "D:\Jenkins\jobs*REDACTED*\workspace\CAPS.msbuild" (default target)
>   (1) -> (Compile target) ->  error MSB4018: The "AssemblyInfo" task
>   failed unexpectedly. System.ArgumentException: version  Parameter
>   name: The specified string is not a valid version number  at
>   Microsoft.Build.Extras.Version.ParseVersion(String version)  at
>   Microsoft.Build.Extras.AssemblyInfo.Execute()  at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()

I've verified that the AssemblyInfo.cs files all look good (as far as I can tell) and nothing seems out of sorts with the msbuild file for the solution.

I've Googled all the derivations of the error that I can think of.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**Comment Responses:**

From the AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.*")]
```

From the msbuild file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectName>CAPS</ProjectName>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <VersionLabel Condition=" '$(VersionLabel)' == '' ">0.0</VersionLabel>
    <AssemblyVersion>2.0.$(VersionLabel)</AssemblyVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This may also be relevant:

```
<Target Name="Compile">
        <ItemGroup>
            <UpdateFiles Include="**\AssemblyInfo.cs" Exclude="**\.svn\**" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <AssemblyInfo AssemblyInfoFiles="@(UpdateFiles)" AssemblyVersion="$(AssemblyVersion)" AssemblyFileVersion="$(AssemblyVersion)"/>

        <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectName).sln" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);RunCodeAnalysis=true" />
</Target>
```

Comment: `The specified string is not a valid version number` - what version number did you try to write?

Comment: Updated the question with the info.

Comment: ...and `$(AssemblyVersion)` gets the expected value? `<Message Text="$(AssemblyVersion)"/>` can show you that.

Comment: Where do I put that line and where can I see the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that your use of the VersionLabel variable is not resolving, and it is trying to write the literal 2.0.$(VersionLabel) into the AssemblyInfo file.

One side note: You are setting AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion to the same number, in a strong named situation you will not be able to hot swap Dll's. Usually AssemblyVersion would be '2.0' and your AssemblyFileVersion would be '2.0.13345.02' or whatever your numbering scheme is. That way a dll built in 2 weeks which would have '2.0' and say '2.0.13352.01' could be swapped in and still work.

If you are publishing the whole package everytime this may not be important, but your are not using the fields correctly.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602/what-are-differences-between-assemblyversion-assemblyfileversion-and-assemblyin) from another question

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug in the task, if you change the [assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.*")] in your assembly info to a version no [assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.0.0")] it'll work.