# Can we add an extra character with the minor value of the assembly version?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to add a character to the assembly version? ex `10.1.1.1a` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/64602/440030

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Assembly versions (specified by [`AssemblyVersionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx)) follow the [`System.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) system, which is *strictly* four numbers.

However, you can use [`AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute.aspx) to give more information.

Answer (score 0):

No:

> [AssemblyVersionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):
>
> All components of the version must be integers greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: i have a dll with same versions but the modified time is different. but i need differentiate 2 same dlls with version or some other file properties. any suggestions?

Comment: _"but i need differentiate 2 same dlls with version or some other file properties."_ - no, you need to make sure there's only one DLL for each version going around. Using a build server might be able to fix the underlying problem you're having. Perhaps you could also use [`AssemblyFileVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.aspx) attribute, where you incorporate the build time into the file version while keeping the assembly version the same.