# Visual Studio not setting assembly version as per my AssemblyVersionAttribute value

Tags: .net, version, versioning, .net-assembly

I am setting this as the version in my `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.13.1231.*")]
```

However, upon compiling, I see in the Windows Explorer file properties that the `Product Version` is still `1.0.0.0`.

What am I missing? I've done this before.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Web Developer Express.

Comment: 'Product Version' != 'Assembly Version'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the AssemblyInformationalVersion which sets the ProductVersion

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Note there is also a File Version as well.

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

This answer provides more details:
[What are differences between AssemblyVersion, AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyInformationalVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602/what-are-differences-between-assemblyversion-assemblyfileversion-and-assemblyin)