# C# Application - Custom Assembly Version Format

Tags: c#, assemblyinfo

Bit of an odd one maybe, but currently looking into if it is possible to implement a custom format for the Assembly Information for a project.

In the Assembly information you are given the option of a 4 number system, so major.minor.build.revision

I have been asked to try and change this to a 5 number system, so something like `1.2.34.556.1234` and wondering whether this is even possible.

I have simply tried just modifying it programmatically, but that just returns the error:

```
Error emitting 'System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute -- 'The version specified '1.2.34.556.1234' is invalid'
```

Comment: Didn't think so....I guess could just save the faked 5 digit version in another field somewhere...

Comment: You should check out this awesome answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/802038/682105

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that purpose, I prefer using the `AssemblyFileVersion` instead of the `AssemblyVersion`.

The former has an open format and can accommodate virtually any additional information, whereas the latter, `AssmeblyVersion` is intended for use by the .NET framework and ***enforces*** a strict numbering scheme that yields compiler errors if infracted.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.0.*")] //Strict Format, for framework use
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("4.0.20.110708")]    //Flexible Format more suitable for product versions
```

**Update:**
Per OP comment, here is how one can access this attribute easily via reflection:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
string version = fvi.FileVersion;
```

Comment: For that case, can you easily get access to `AssemblyFileVersion` programmatically through reflection?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because the constructor for AssemblyVersionAttribute takes up to 4 values in the string.:

> The format of the version string is: major. minor. build. revision.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.assemblyversionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`AssemblyVersionAttribute` is converted to the [Version class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It has only the major,minor,build,revision number: you cannot use 5 numbers.

If you want to use more numbers you can use the [AssemblyInformationalVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It is not a `Version Class` but a `string` for a more descriptive assembly versioning:

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.12.0.3050.1234 Release - Any CPU")]
```

But you should provide anyway `AssemblyVersion` and/or `AssemblyFileVersion` without the 5th number