# Change version to dll issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I have an assembly of a library project, That Had the dll version number 2.0.0 and I changed it to 2.1.0.0 by clicking right over project -> properties -> application -> Assembly Information ... here I've changed Assembly Version and File Version.

Now, the problem is That after the modification, when i try to reference this dll in another solution, i get the error:
Can not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly, Version = 2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 78ffe0bb48d8c173'

Anyone knows why is it Asking for version = 2.0.0.0 if I changed it to 2.1.0.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your project file saves the version of the dll you're referencing:

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

If you don't want it to use a specific version, you can set the 'Specific Version' to `false` in Visual Studio (in the properties section of the dll in the reference list)

You also might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602/what-are-differences-between-assemblyversion-assemblyfileversion-and-assemblyin/65062#65062) to decide if you actually want to increment your assembly version.