# C# installer ~ file version in Windows explorer different to that of the project

Tags: c#, installation, setup-project

I'm starting out in C# devlopment and have created a small test application with an installer.

In the AssemblyInfo code, I can see that the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion are set as 1.0.0.0 as it the installers version number (see screenshot 1 below)

When I browse to the setup.exe file using windows explorer and look at the File Version column, it shows a totally different number, 15.0.27005.2 as shown in screenshot 2 below.

Would someone be able to help me work out why this is showing differently please. I don't think I've missed anything obvious.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: I see the same version number **`15.0.27005.2`** for another Visual Studio Installer **`setup.exe`**, and hence it must be the build version for the **`setup.exe`** bootstrapper application itself - which is included with **`Visual Studio 2017`** setup projects in the output folder (side-by-side with the MSI).

Answer (score 0):

Making a educated guess here:

- The values in assemblyinfo.cs to affect only the product exe/dll you build which not seen in the above images
- If you run the installer and look at the [assembly version/assembly file version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602/what-are-differences-between-assemblyversion-assemblyfileversion-and-assemblyin) of the installed product exe/dll in explorer, it should read `1.0.0.0`
- The `15.0.27005.2` seen in the (explorer) image above shows the "File Version" of the installer file (setup.exe). I don't know where this value came from or if you can have any control it over via the installer project settings
- The `1.0.0.0` seen in the (MyInstaller) image is the logical version of the installer itself.