# What's going on with assembly and class versions compatibility?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, versioning, fileversioninfo

I'm struggling with proper dependencies versioning on releases. I've read in some articles that every change to AssemblyVersion in a library will cause the need of rebuilding all assemblies referencing this library. If it's true I need to be super careful when designing release cycles of dependent assemblies, right?

I wanted to verify the thesis by myself and... well, I noticed it is not the truth at all.

I made a console app which referenced dep1.dll (assembly version 1.0.0.0) and built it. Then I changed dep1.dll to version 2.0.0.0, built it and swapped it with version 1.0.0.0. When running console application I expected error *"The assembly dep1.dll with version 1.0.0.0 couldn't be found"*. And you know what? Nothing special happened, the app used the library like it was targetting that version since the beginning.

ConsoleApp1/Program.cs

```
using dep1;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new Class1();
            a.Prop1 = "asdf";
            Console.WriteLine(a.Prop1);
        }
    }

    public class Implementation : Interface1
    {
        public int Super { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

dep1/Class1.cs

```
namespace dep1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    }

    public interface Interface1
    {
        int Super { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's the same with interfaces.

Could you please explain why my test didn't work? This, other SO answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65062/2811109)) and article by haacked [on versioning interfaces](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/02/21/versioning-issues-with-abstract-base-classes-and-interfaces.aspx/) really confused me.