# How to specify the assembly version for a .NET Core project?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I noticed in new .NET Core projects there is no `AssemblyInfo.cs` file created. I have seen that you can still set assembly attributes such as `AssemblyVersion` and so forth.

Are there still any valid reasons to use an AssemblyInfo.cs file?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can absolutely create an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file and configure your assembly like you did in the past. Of course, since the properties are set using assembly attributes, you do not need to use `AssemblyInfo` but can choose any other file name or even an existing one.

That being said, the reason that the `AssemblyInfo.cs` is no longer included in the default templates is that the new SDK-style project type supports setting this information within the `csproj` project file.

So the usual approach to setting the version of your assembly would be to set the `Version` property within your project file (or have that automatically set as part of your build process). For example:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <Version>1.2.3</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  …
</Project>
```

Since this is a MSBuild property, you can also set this during the build process e.g. with `dotnet build /p:Version=1.2.3`.

There are also the properties `VersionPrefix` and `VersionSuffix` which can be used to automatically construct version numbers from the environment (e.g. Git commit ids, or build numbers).

In addition to the version related properties, there are also [some more NuGet properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties) you can set in the project file, which makes the `AssemblyInfo.cs` mostly redundant.

Answer (score 21):

According to [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/assembly-info), these days, we have few flexible ways to set up assembly attributes.

1. Use old-style AssemblyInfo.cs file (create manually).

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute("...")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyCopyrightAttribute("...")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyDescriptionAttribute("...")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("...")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("...")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute("...")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute("...")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0-dev01234567")]
```

2. Use MSBuild's properties to generate assembly attributes on build time (may be static in `your.csproj` or passed via command line arguments like  `/property:Version=1.0.0-dev01234567`).

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Company>...</Company>
        <Copyright>...</Copyright>
        <Description>...</Description>
        <Product>...</Product>
        <AssemblyTitle>...</AssemblyTitle>
        <Version>1.0.0-dev01234567</Version>
    </PropertyGroup>

    ...
</Project>
```

Note: you may merge both solutions but avoid duplicates of assembly attributes.

Comment: You may need to add `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>` if there is a conflict when using BOTH styles of setting attributes.

Answer (score 18):

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and .NET Core 6.

1. Right click on the project in Solution Explorer
2. Edit Project File

Here is an example project file containing `Version`, `AssemblyVersion` and `FileVersion`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

Comment: what's the difference between those 3 `version` settings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602/what-are-differences-between-assemblyversion-assemblyfileversion-and-assemblyin

Answer (score 11):

1. From Your Project -> Select **Properties**
2. On left panel select **Package/General**
3. At field **Assembly version** and **File version** enter your version (ex: 1.0.0.0)

[image]

Comment: This is confusing in Visual Studio 2022 and .Net 7.  The Package > General Section start with a check box - Generate NuGet package on build operations.  This helped me to understand they are indeed the Assembly Version and File Version with or without Nuget

Answer (score 8):

Reasons for still using an AssemblyInfo.cs file might include

1. you want to share some of the AssemblyInfo across projects,
   which you can do with a file
2. you might have a code-generation process that spits out the assemblyinfo
3. the project file format doesn't yet support all the attributes you might want to use. The project Sdk knows how to auto-generate a *limited set* of `[AssembyAttributes]` from Xml Elements with matching names in the `csproj` file, but it doesn't support autogeneration of arbitrary `[AssembyAttributes]` or other metadata for your assembly.
4. AssemblyInfo.cs is “just” a source code file, you might have other metadata – whether AssemblyAttributes or classes or other – you want to keep all in one easily found place.

Answer (score 0):

See this article for a on **.NET Core Project Versioning** that provisions for a flexible way to generate meaningful version numbers. The approach leverages on MSBuild and the new project file format.

[scottdorman.blog/2018/08/20/net-core-project-versioning](https://scottdorman.blog/2018/08/20/net-core-project-versioning/)

GitHub repository [github.com/scottdorman/assembly-build-versioning](https://github.com/scottdorman/assembly-build-versioning)

Relevant assembly properties are set in a `common.props` file. A sample of this file might look like

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Product>WebApp</Product>
    <Company>MyCompany</Company>
    <Copyright>Copyright © 2024</Copyright>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
    <VersionMinor>2</VersionMinor>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>$(VersionMajor).$(VersionMinor)</VersionPrefix>
    <VersionSuffix>preview</VersionSuffix>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateReleaseNotes Condition="'$(GenerateReleaseNotes)' == ''">false</GenerateReleaseNotes>
    <GenerateAssemblyBuildDateAttribute Condition="'$(GenerateAssemblyBuildDateAttribute)' == ''">true</GenerateAssemblyBuildDateAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add common assemblyinfo type version properties to a file named Directory.Build.props in the same directory as the sln file and your project DLLs will be built with the version info e.g. sample file:

```html
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Company>JB Solutions</Company>
        <Copyright>Copyright (c) 2024</Copyright>
        <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <FileVersion>1.0.0.6</FileVersion>
        <version>1.0.0.6</version>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```