# Set build version in .net 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5

How do you set an assembly version in .NET 5.0 ?

There is no "Assembly Information" button anymore and no assemblyinfo.cs etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433665/how-to-specify-the-assembly-version-for-a-net-core-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET 5.0 I'm setting the Assembly Version in my `Project.csproj` file this way :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <Version>2.0.0</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>2.0.0.32</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>2.0.0.32</FileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```