# Difference in VS project reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to add a specific version of DocumentFormat.OpenXml -> 2.5.5631.0 using Reference Manager. However, after browsing to the DLL and adding it, the project file is showing another version!?

[image]

Any ideas how to fix it so that the csproj file has the same version as the one shown in Reference Manager? Thanks!

Comment: That's what you should expect. Not all library authors use a single version number for native file version and managed assembly version. They can differ from each other.

Comment: [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies?page=1&tab=active#tab-top) or [What are differences between AssemblyVersion, AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyInformationalVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602/what-are-differences-between-assemblyversion-assemblyfileversion-and-assemblyin)