# nuget pack doesn't read assembly version from Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I'm following along [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#new-file-with-default-values) about creating a nuget package with `nuget.exe`. I'm trying to create a nuspec file out of a Visual Studio project.

According to the docs, when you run

```
> nuget spec
```

From the directory where your `.csproj` file resides, it creates a tokenized `.nuspec` file. Then, when you run `nuget pack <project-name>.csproj` the values from the project file are used to replace the tokens in the nuspec file.

So in my example, I have a project called `Logger1`. After running `nuget spec`, I have the following `.nuspec`

```
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>Yoav Klein</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="expression">MIT</license>
...
```

Now, [this doc](https://To%20use%20these%20tokens,%20run%20nuget%20pack%20with%20the%20project%20file%20rather%20than%20just%20the%20.nuspec.%20For%20example,%20when%20using%20the%20following%20command,%20the%20$id$%20and%20$version$%20tokens%20in%20a%20.nuspec%20file%20are%20replaced%20with%20the%20project%27s%20AssemblyName%20and%20AssemblyVersion%20values:%20%20ps%20%20Copy%20nuget%20pack%20MyProject.csproj) says that:

> To use these tokens, run nuget pack with the project file rather than just the .nuspec. For example, when using the following command, the $id$ and $version$ tokens in a .nuspec file are replaced with the project's AssemblyName and AssemblyVersion values:

```
nuget pack MyProject.csproj
```

My Assembly version is:

```
# AssemblyInfo.cs

// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.6.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Now I run `nuget pack Logger1.csproj` and I expect the version of the package to be drawn from the `AssemblyVersion` of the project, as promised by the docs.

After creating the package, I examine the .nuspec file in the package created:

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Logger1</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
```

As you can see, for some reason, it doesn't take the correct value of the `AssemblyVersion` which is `1.6.0`, but rather always uses the value `1.0.0`.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

NuGet Version: 5.8.1.7021

---

Just to confirm, after building the dll, I can see that the assembly version is 1.6.0:

```
PS> [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName("$(pwd)\bin\Debug\Logger1.dll")

Version        Name
-------        ----
1.6.0.0        Logger1
```

Comment: I’m not sure, but whether you know the differences among `AssemblyVersion`, `File version` and `Package version`? Actually, if you want to confirm whether the `AssemblyVersion` has changed, you can install this packed NuGet package to a project, and build the project. The project will generate a `.dll` file which is related to this NuGet package, and usually it stores under `..\bin\Debug`. You can open PowerShell and enter command like `[Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName("full path to this dll file").Version` and you can see the `AssemblyVersion`.

Comment: But perhaps you just want to change the [File Version/Package Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602/what-are-differences-between-assemblyversion-assemblyfileversion-and-assemblyin)? I guess :D

Comment: @Tianyu, see the edit

Comment: I’m a little confused, I thought you want to change the assembly version but it seems not what you want. Do you mean you want to change `1.0.0`? And to confirm, where did you see this `1.0.0`?

Comment: @Tianyu, take a look at the edit again. Hope it's clear enough this time

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, may I ask where did you find the created .nuspec file when you were trying to examine it? Is it the same `.nuspec` file that created by `nuget spec` and modified by `nuget pack MyProject.csproj` command? As, tested on my side, after running `pack` command, I didn’t see that my .nuspec file was changed(they are still `$id$`, `$version$`).

Comment: @Tianyu, the original nuspec file should not change. The .nuspec file I'm talking about is the one that's contained in the created .nupkg.

Comment: I got it, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue looks quite like a potential issue.

I did more tests and, after analyzing, I saw that, during the packing process, always, there was an error message like `XXXXX is required`. I confirmed several times, and referred to the [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#replacement-tokens), which mentioned that the tokens will be replaced with the value which set in my `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

For example, if I set `[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Company")]`, as promised, the $author$ token should be replaced with "Company" but it wasn’t replaced, instead it reported `Authors is required`  error, which looks like nuget.exe didn’t check my `AssemblyInfo.cs` file at all.

I then found this thread: [NuGet again throwing exceptions "authors is required"… ignoring csproj/nuspec replacement tokens](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9954). And I saw one workaround/solution > name the downloaded nuget.exe file to nuget.exe file and right-click the file > property > check the `Unblock` option beside `This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer.` message. And it seems it’s the solution and let nuget.exe work normally to find and check `AssemblyInfo.cs` file then replace the tokens.

**In short(whole solution)**

Download nuget.exe from official website and make sure that its name is nuget.exe. Then right-click the nuget.exe file and choose Properties. Switch to General tab, check the `Unblock` option. Go to your project folder, clear the project cache first(delete `bin`, `obj` folders, close your solution in VS and delete the hidden `.vs` folder, remove the `.nuspec` file and `.nupkg` file), and then use `nuget.exe spec` in command prompt to generate a new `.nuspec` file, edit it to what you want. After that run `nuget.exe pack yourproject.csproj` command line to pack your NuGet package.

[image]

**In short(reason)**

In my opinion, the downloaded nuget.exe file is blocked.

Comment: @Tiaynu, Good job !