# How can I maintain a shared AssemblyFileVersion and seperate AssemblyVersions for each of my project assemblies?

Tags: c#

I'm using a linked AssemblyInfo.cs file to set the AssemblyFileVersion for all of my class libraries.

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("6.60.3.4")]
```

I'm using the local/default AssemblyInfo.cs file for everything else.

```
//example of AssemblyVersion set in project AssemblyInfo.cs    
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("6.60.3.1")]
```

My result is that the AssemblyFileVersion and the AssemblyVersion are both getting set to the AssemblyFileVersion value.

How can I maintain a shared AssemblyFileVersion and seperate AssemblyVersions for each of my project assemblies?

**EDIT**

I was under the impression that I could/should use the AssemblyFileVersion to track the release version for all dll assemblies in my project. The thought would be to have the exe and dlls all have the same AssemblyFileVersion. The AssemblyVersion would only be incremented when modifications occurred to that specific dll. This logic makes sense to me. Please advise if there are more logical approaches to handling large projects

Comment: By definition, the version you are referring to no longer has anything to do with a specific assembly. I assume you mean a suite version or something similar. What happens when you add an assembly? Is it's first release version 6.60.3.4?

Comment: See edit above. Hopefully this will clarify what I'm attempting to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My question was correctly stated, but I'm wondering if I was misled a little. I was using the Windows file properties dialog to confirm that my ProductVersion and FileVersion were getting set properly.

I added the following to my shared AssemblyInfo.cs file and it started working as I expected.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("6.60.0.0")]    
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("6.60.0.0")]
```

Any thoughts why this would update the AssemblyVersion instead of just this

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("6.60.0.0")]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following post, [What are differences between AssemblyVersion, AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyInformationalVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64602/299327), recommends that you do the opposite.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14835/299327) provides a an implementation that could be adapted to suit your needs.

Comment: Your post was helpful in allowing me to see how some use the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion.

Comment: @faldeland I'm glad it was helpful. Please feel free to upvote and accept it. If it doesn't answer you question, let me know what needs to be added or fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no simple solution for this. I think the simplest solution would be to build your class libraries separately first and make the other build depend on that. In general, trying to manipulate values in the AssemblyInfo file is futile.

You could mimic a system like TeamCity. They do it by pulling all of the source, then editing the AssemblyInfo file with the version numbers supplied in the web UI before actually building.

Comment: @faldeland When you look at dll or exe's properties the version number displayed there will reflect what is in the AssemblyInfo file. The AssemblyInfo version is auto incremented when you build so if you build all of your assemblies together, even if there were no code changes to some of them, the versions will be updated.